# jQuery - set input value to previous value on blur if empty

Tags: jquery, blur

I've spent a couple of hours on this and couldn't find anything to help so have thrown in the towel. I am simply trying to restore the previous value of an input box if the user clears it out and leaves nothing when the input loses focus. So for example, if it says "Brisbane, Australia" in my input box, and the user removes that text from the input and then presses tab, I want it to revert the input back to "Brisbane, Australia". Here is my code:

```
$('input#search-location').on("focus", function() {
  $(this).data("previous-value", $(this).val());
}); 

$('input#search-location').on("blur", function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    // alert($(this).data("previous-value"));
    $(this).val($(this).data("previous-value"));
  }
});
```

Both events fire, and if I uncomment the alert in the blur function, it correctly displays the previous value. But nothing appears in my input box, and no errors in the console. I guess it's something silly I'm missing... I appreciate any help!

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/8JxVF/

Comment: indeed it does work...

Comment: Works for me too here http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7r9Lg/ ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work and does here [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7r9Lg/)

Note you need to execute your code after the page elements have rendered, so you need to wrap the code in

```
$(function() { ... });
```

Alternative if you want to set it to the default value it had when the page loaded, try

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/YKSxb/)

```
$('input#search-location').on("blur", function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    $(this).val(this.defaultValue);
  }
});
```

Newer browsers will give a hint here:

```
<input placeholder="Type your name" />
```

and you can help older browsers support it

```
$(function() {
  if (!placeholderIsSupported) {
    $('#search-location1')
    .val($('#search-location1').attr("placeholder"))
    .on("blur", function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
      }
    })
    .on("focus",function() {
      if ($(this).val()==$(this).attr("placeholder")) $(this).val("");
    });
  }  
});

function placeholderIsSupported() {
 var test = document.createElement('input');
 return ('placeholder' in test);
}
```

Comment: Yep it is working in the fiddles (should have made one before I posted). I have the code within document ready, and I know the events get fired because I get the alert when I uncomment it. I want the previous value to be restored rather than the value when the page was loaded, but thanks for that code, that's handy to know about `this.defaultValue`.

Comment: I already have a placeholder on the input and that is working, I tried removing it and it didn't help with my problem though. I'm using Rails and just updated to the latest jQuery gem which means it's using version 1.10.1, still having the same problem. Weird!

Comment: Take your form and paste it into a new page, take the code you have and add it. It will work. Now add bit by bit till it fails. You should have found your problem. For example a form "beautifier"

Comment: Yep you're right, I did that and found the problem is something to do with the Google Places Autocomplete which I have attached to the input. Should have mentioned I had that earlier sorry, seems obvious now that it is the culprit. I still can't get it to work but at least I know why it's happening now. Thanks for your help.